# compiling with HDF5: unable to link library files (fortran 90)

Tags: hyperlink, fortran, hdf5

I am currently try to compile these files using HDF5
I have directly linked and included everything necessary ( I think) but still the compile unable to find the files that is needed

**This is my Makefile:**

```
CC = h5cc
FC = h5fc
LD = h5fc

FDEBUG  = -std -g -traceback
CFLAGS  = -g -O0 -Wall -pedantic
FFLAGS  = -g -O0 -Wall -I$(H5DIR)/include -L$(H5DIR)/lib/libhdf5hl_fortran.a
LDFLAGS = -I$(H5DIR)/include -L$(H5DIR)/lib/libhdf5hl_fortran.a
#LDFLAGS = -I$(MKLROOT)/include -L$(MKLROOT) -mkl=sequential
#     -opt-block-factor=16 -opt-prefetch=4 \

.SUFFIXES:
.SUFFIXES: .c .f .f90 .F90 .o

OBJS = timing.o    \
       kinds.o \
       rw_matrix.o \

EXE  = matmul_omp.exe

all: $(EXE)

$(EXE): $(OBJS) matmul_omp.o
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

.f90.o:
    -$(RM) -f $*.o $*.mod
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -c $<

.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

.PHONEY: clean
clean:
```

**THis is the err:**

```
h5fc -I/curc/tools/x_86_64/rh6/hdf5/1.8.13/szip/2.1/zlib/1.2.8/jpeglib/9a/openmpi/1.8.2/intel/13.0.0/include -L/curc/tools/x_86_64/rh6/hdf5/1.8.13/szip/2.1/zlib/1.2.8/jpeglib/9a/openmpi/1.8.2/intel/13.0.0/lib/libhdf5hl_fortran.a  -o matmul_omp.exe timing.o matmul_omp.o

gfortran: /usr/lib64/libhdf5hl_fortran.a: No such file or directory
gfortran: /usr/lib64/libhdf5_hl.a: No such file or directory
gfortran: /usr/lib64/libhdf5_fortran.a: No such file or directory
gfortran: /usr/lib64/libhdf5.a: No such file or directory
```

As you can see that I directly link libhdf5hl_fortran.a. but i dont know why the error is giving a different directory /usr/lib64/

Comment: Where is the library installed? What is the value of `H5DIR`?

Comment: Both the include (`-I`) and library (`-L`) paths look wonky to me. Intel include files inside an openmpi directory, fair enough, but that's inside a jpeglib directory inside a zlib directory inside an szip directory ... you get the picture.  If those are correct the installation is weird and I'm not surprised the makefile can't find the libraries.  All this is a long-winded way of asking the same questions as @VladimirF.

Comment: H5DIR = /curc/tools/x_86_64/rh6/hdf5/1.8.13/szip/2.1/zlib/1.2.8/jpeglib/9a/openmpi/1.8.2/intel/13.0.0/ 
I have checked inside the directory and I found these files in there. Still the problem remainds

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a couple of things wrong here.

If you are using `h5fc` then you shouldn't need to add all the include and lib paths. That is the whole point of the helper applications.

You are adding the paths that have Intel, yet your `h5fc` has a GNU (gfortran) error.

The gfortran build of HDF5 looks as if it does not have the fortran bindings built.

I would suggest trying the following. Using the full paths (as you have done) but call `ifort` instead of `h5fc`:

```
ifort -I/curc/tools/x_86_64/rh6/hdf5/1.8.13/szip/2.1/zlib/1.2.8/jpeglib/9a/openmpi/1.8.2/intel/13.0.0/include \
      -L/curc/tools/x_86_64/rh6/hdf5/1.8.13/szip/2.1/zlib/1.2.8/jpeglib/9a/openmpi/1.8.2/intel/13.0.0/lib/libhdf5hl_fortran.a  \
      -o matmul_omp.exe timing.o matmul_omp.o
```